# Prevent bluetooth keyboard from sleeping

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, usb, bluetooth, power-management

After a few minutes of inactivity (10mn?), my keyboard go to sleep. I have to press a key, then, wait 5 long seconds before I can use it again...

First, some technical details :

- Linux Mint 20 ulyana - Cinnamon (Ubuntu 20.04)
- TP-Link UB400
- Bluetooth USB dongle Microsoft Surface Ergonomic Keyboard

[image]
[image]

I paired the keyboard using bluetoothctl. This is the only way I found to enter passkey, since blueman-mananger didn't ask for a passkey.

**What I tried:**

- 1 - Checking the bios (motherboard: Asus H87-PLUS C2) for usb power management options. I found nothing
- 2 - grub setting. Nothing changed.

*commands*:

```
sudo sed -i 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="[a-z ]*/& usbcore.autosuspend=-1/' /etc/default/grub    
sudo update-grub2    
reboot
cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend
-1
```

- 3 - Looking for power management in parameters. Found nothing.
  [image]
  [image]
- 4 - Editing /etc/bluetooth/main.cfg. Still nothing.

config + reboot:

```
AutoEnable=true
FastConnectable=true
```

Any other ideas? Bluetooth options? USB options? Keyboard options? Maybe some kind of nondisturbing script + cron to keep it alive?

(I know "Mint is not Linux", but I hope you guys are more open minded compared to the askubuntu Stack Exchange community :-) )

EDIT:
I connected a bluetooth headphone. It looks like only the keyboard is falling asleep. The headphone is kept awake.
I cannot manually connect the keyboard from blueman manager (right clic + connect) when it's sleeping, but I can connect the headphone.

Comment: It's possible it's actually done by the keyboard firmware and there is nothing you can do about it. Is this feature mentioned in the keyboard manual?

Comment: The only instruction in the manual is how to hold a button under the keyboard during 3s to enter pairing mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same keyboard, same OS and same problem. There are a lot of complains about this but hardly a solution.

I did a lot of research and I thing the best would be to dedicate the bluetooth dongle to the keyboard by setting it in **HID mode**. You would basically "upload" the pairing with the keyboard on the adapter. The adapter would then manage the connection with the keyboard on its own, showing itself as regular USB keyboard to the system. Your TP-Link adapter seems to have a CSR 8150 chipset that should work. Downside: That adapter would be *either* in HID mode *or* in regular HCI mode where it serves as a general bluetooth adapter.

You can see [here a repo](https://github.com/wmertens/textblade-dongler) of someone who did something like this for another keyboard. Their setup requires you to setup VMs; I think it can be done much easier:

### Compatibility test

Run `bccmd psget 0x3cd` (maybe with sudo) and see if you get an error. If not, your bluetooth adapter should be compatible. My adapter failed (despite supposedly having a CSR8150 chipset). Did not break anything, but did not fix it either.

### Extract keyboard and adapter MAC

With active keyboard connectin, run `hcitool con` to get the MAC address of your keybaord.
Next, get the MAC address of your bluetooth adapter with `hcitool dev`.

### Edit the script

Save the following script (taken from the linked repo and modified) as a text file and put both MAC addresses in the first lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
MAC=your_adapter_MAC
DEV=hci0
CTRL=your_keyboard_MAC

function die() {
  echo "FATAL: $@" 1>&2
  exit 1
}

function readKeys() {
  export Key= EDiv= Rand=
  export t= $(cat "/var/lib/bluetooth/$CTRL/$MAC/info" | sed -n -e '/^\[LongTermKey/,/^\[/p' | grep -E '^(Key|EDiv|Rand)=[A-F0-9]+$')
  if [ -z "$Key" ] || [ -z "$EDiv" ] || [ -z "$Rand" ]; then
    return 1
  fi
  return 0
}

function toHex() { echo "obase=16; $1" | bc; }
function revbytes(){ local b=""; for ((i=2;i<=${#1};i+=2)); do b=$b${1: -i:2}; done; echo $b; }
function rev16(){ local b=""; for ((i=0;i<${#1};i+=4)); do b=$b${1: i+2:2}${1: i:2}; done; echo $b; }
function pad() { local b=000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000$1; echo ${b: -$2*2:$2*2}; }
function makeToken() { echo $(echo $MAC|tr -d : )1482$(rev16 $(pad $(toHex $EDiv) 2))$(revbytes $(pad $(toHex $Rand) 8))$(rev16 $(pad $Key 16)); }
function formatToken() { local b=""; for ((i=0;i<${#1};i+=4)); do b="$b${1: i:4} "; done; echo $b | tr A-Z a-z; }

readKeys || die "Could not extract pairing keys"
token=$(formatToken $(makeToken))
[ ${#token} -eq 84 ] || die "Token $token has incorrect length"

echo "Writing $token to /dev/$DEV"
bccmd psload -s 0 /dev/stdin <<-EOF
// PSKEY_USR42
&02b4 = $token
// PSKEY_INITIAL_BOOTMODE
&03cd = 0002
&04b0 = 03c0 03cc 22c0
&04b1 = 01f9 0042
&04b2 = 02bf 03c0 03cc 02bd 000d 000e 215f
&04b8 = 0000
&04b9 = 0000
&04ba = 0001
&04f8 = 0000
&04f9 = 0001
&0538 = 100b
&0539 = 0001
&053a = 0001
&053b = 0000 0000 0000
&053c = 0002
&053d = 0000
&053e = 0002 0001 000a 0008 0010 0008 0020 0008 0040 0004 0080 0002 0140 0001 0200 0002
EOF
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  die 'write failed :-('
fi

bccmd psread | grep '&02b4'
echo "Make sure the above output is $token"
```

### Run the script

Run the script as root and your adapter should be set to HID mode, fixing not only the reconnect-problem but also working e.g. for the HDD encryption password at boot time of in BIOS.

Comment: I got rid of this junk, so I can't test your solution, but since you tell me it's working for you, I guess it could have worked for me... so I will accept the answer and thank you.