# Ping already connected bluetooth keyboard

Tags: bluetooth, power-management

I have a terribly lazy bluetooth keyboard which I try to keep awake (see: [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/626387/prevent-bluetooth-keyboard-from-sleeping)). If I don't hit any key, it sleeps after a time between 30s to 10mn (depending of how long I used it before, I guess) and it takes at least 5 frustrating seconds to reconnect. So I want to run a script that send/ask something (I don't know yet) every few seconds to keep it awake.

The first step is to find it.

I tried l2ping:

```
$ sudo l2ping E0:6A:4E:71:85:F6
Can't connect: Host is down
```

I tried with pybluez (python), but it's a failure too:

```
>>> import bluetooth
>>> bluetooth.discover_devices()
[]
>>> bluetooth.find_service(address='all')
[]
>>> sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
>>> sock.connect(("E0:6A:4E:71:85:F6", 1))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in connect
_bluetooth.error: (112, 'Host is down')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in connect
bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: [Errno 112] Host is down
>>>  "<string>", line 5, in connect
bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: [Errno 112] Host is down
>>>
```

I tried bluetoothhctl:

```
watch -n 60 echo -e 'connect E0:6A:4E:71:85:F6' | bluetoothctl
```

(And it falls asleep anyway)

The next step will be to keep it busy in order to keep it awake.

Any help is appreciated.